# How can I whitelist localhost

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use a continueURL for firebase and need to whitelist domains. In order to test this, I want to add a localhost domain to test against, but it seems like there is no way to get around the fact that it needs to be a valid domain. Can anyone help?

Comment: No because it checks that a particular TXT record exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could try 127.0.0.1 It also relates to localhost.
Or you could try with the IP of IT (you should declare a static one)

Answer (score 0):

Localhost should be whitelisted by default.